# I am new with Kotlin. I am trying to change text from "Hello World" to "Next" but -> Hardcoded string "Next", should use `@string` resource

Tags: android, kotlin

[error code: Hardcoded string "Next", should use `@string` resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp5VT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its lint warning. It is showing you best practice that you should follow. Instead of using "Next" directly on TextView add a string resource somewhat like this in your strings.xml

```
<string name="next">Next</string>
```

and use on TextView like this

```
android:text="@string/next"
```